# Use an array inside a query string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Im trying to pass an array that I already found by a query into another query.  For example:

```
$first_query = "SELECT id FROM from Table WHERE user = '{$_SESSION['id'}'";
$result = mysql_query($first_query,$connection);
$ids = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This is where it gets tricky for me.  I want to pass $ids into the next query.

```
$id_implode = implode(", ", $ids)
$second_query = "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id = '{$id_implode}';
```

The second query doesnt seem to be working.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your second query's syntax is wrong. Once evaluated it should read

```
select * from Table2 where id in (1,2,3)
```

ditch the curly braces and change the = to in. Don't use OR - that's a dumb way of ignoring good sql functionality

**EDIT**: Teneff's comment makes a very good point - why are you approaching the problem in this way? If there is a relationship between the tables they can be joined and all the data you want can be retrieved in a single query. If for some reason you can't / won't join the tables you could at least try a sub-query

```
select * from table2 where id in (select id from table where user = $_SESSION['id']);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use the `IN` syntax:

```
$id_implode = implode("', '", $ids);
$second_query = "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id in ('{$id_implode}');
```

Comment: `where id in` must be surrounded by paraenthesis `()`.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

To use a `where` statement with multiple entries to match on, use `in ()`.

```
$id_implode = "'".implode("', '", $ids)."'"
$second_query = "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id in ({$id_implode});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use IN

```
$id_implode = implode(", ", $ids)
$second_query = "SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id IN '({$id_implode})';
```

This assumes that $ids is made of int of course, otherwise you have to enclose eache entry in quotes. that means

```
IN (6,7,8,9)//this doesn't need quotes

IN ('lemon', 'orange')//needs quotes
```